# Jquery not expanding li items correctly

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to get my news archives to expand individualy. So for example if I click on 2014 then the months January and February must show but they must remain closed and if you click on January the January must open and February must be closed.

The problem I'm having is that if I click on 2014 then it opens, but if I click on January or February then 2014 closes instead of staying open and the month I click opens up.

My html

```
<div class="news-archive">
    <ul class="yearly-archive">
        <li class="year_2014">2014
            <ul class="monthly-archive">
                <li class="january">
                    <ul class="archive">
                        <li>January 1</li>
                        <li>January 2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="february">
                    <ul class="archive">
                        <li>February 1</li>
                        <li>February 2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My css

```
.year_2014 .monthly-archive {
    display: none;
}

.january .archive{
    display: none;
}
```

My js

```
$('.year_2014').click(function(){
    $('.year_2014 .monthly-archive').toggle();
});

$('.january').click(function(){
    $('.january .archive').toggle();
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aqjdjjga/)

Comment: Will you add 50 `click` event handlers if you have news for 50 years? And 12 `click` event handlers for 12 months?

Comment: About your problem: add `return false;` after `$('.january .archive').toggle();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do the tasks simply without writing click event for each and every li elements,

```
$('div.news-archive ul li').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     var elem = $(this).find('ul:first');
     elem.length ? elem.toggle() : $(this).closest('ul').toggle();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aqjdjjga/4/)

Answer (score 3):

Use **[stopPropagation();](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)**  Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree

```
$('.year_2014').click(function () {
    $('.year_2014 .monthly-archive').toggle();
});

$('.january').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.january .archive').toggle();
});

$('.february').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.february .archive').toggle();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aqjdjjga/1/)

Comment: You might want to explain that this happens because the ul's are nested, so that when you're clicking a child, you're also still clicking the parent.

Comment: @SanderKoedood Now see updated code, That time i just posted answer

Comment: @upvoters: If you let him in his own way, then he would write a click event for each month. :) Is this a right way of writing the code.? :) :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy You proved again you are very Genius :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy this answer explains why the code doesn't work ... yes you can provide a function for all elements but isn't the point of the question itself your answer doesn't provide the explanation of the problem this can be more usefull for future users

Answer (score 0):

You can use as also:

```
$('.year_2014').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('year_2014 monthly-archive');
});

$('.january').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('january archive');
});

$('.february').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('february archive');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aqjdjjga/3/)